# Like count button like Facebook

Tags: android

```
if (like == true) {
  items.setLikes(items.getLikes() + 1);
  timeline_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  //   Toast.makeText(getContext(),"like: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Operation_class operation_class = new Operation_class();
  operation_class.update_likes(items.getTimeline_title());
  like = false;

} else {
  items.setLikes(items.getLikes() - 1);
  likecount1 = true;
  timeline_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now I click the next view like button it decrease the value but it should increase.
Like should be increment in different view in recycle-view it is possible like Facebook.

Comment: Can you confirm like is true ?

Comment: Yeah but when I click next view like button it decrease the like value.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I click next view like button it decrease the like value

This is because you set  `like = false;` in the **end of if block**. Just **remove** this line and the like will be incremented every time the button is clicked.

Comment: If I set like = false then like value will be increases.when the else fuction will run if I want to unlike

Comment: like is a `button` ?